# React native change color scheme in real time problem android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, color-scheme

What I'm doing is giving the user the possibility to change the color of the device scheme (`light or dark`) in real time.

On `ios` it works, when on the device I press the key combination: `Command + Uppercase + A`.

Event is intercepted, and the theme is changed in real time.

When on `Android` I try to change the theme color from the button menu, as you can see from the image.

[image]

The event is not intercepted I have to exit the app for a moment and then re-enter to make the changes happen.

I'm using `import {useColorScheme} from 'react-native'`.

I also tried `import {useColorScheme} from 'react-native-appearance'`, but on ios the realtime thing doesn't work.

How can I solve?

Comment: You ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, on iOS the theme change worked fine however on Android it did not trigger a re-render.

I fixed this by doing the following thing:
Create an **appstate** listener which detects when an app is coming back from the **background to the foreground**.

Then in the listener function I checked if the current theme is equal to the theme selected in the device. If the theme changed I updated my redux store which contains my colorScheme.

And by doing that all my components subscribed to my reduxstate just re-renderd.